# If I export data from GA4 to BigQuery and then to Looker Studio using connector, will it implement _TABLE_SUFFIX under the hood?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, looker-studio

I export my data from GA4 to BigQuery, and now I need to create data visualization using Looker Studio. I use BigQuery connector data as the data source like this

[image]

so I can access my GA4 data from BigQuery in Looker Studio in certain date range like this

[image]

as far as I know, one of BigQuery pricing is based on data querying processing. I assume if I use the connector like I did above I will query all columns available from my database table because it seems all the metric and dimensions are available

but how about the date? as far as I know, BigQuery will make 'date compartment' like the image below

[image]

so we can query more efficient using `_TABLE_SUFFIX` to reduce the cost like the query below

```
SELECT
  event_name,
  platform,
  user_pseudo_id,
  user_id,
FROM
  `database.analytics_0000000000000.events_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20230315' AND '20230401'
ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC
```

so my question is .....

If I set the date range in my Looker Studio that fetch data from BigQuery connector. will I read all the data from my BigQuery table? Will I read all data since the beginning I create the BigQuery database ? or will it implement `_TABLE_SUFFIX` under the hood so I will only be charged on the certain date range?